# How to apply a function to every element in a matrix

Tags: matlab, function, matrix

I have a 58×58 matrix `A`, and I have a function

```
X = 1 + A^2 + cos(theta)/(1+A)
```

where `A` is said 58×58 matrix.

How I can call the elements of matrix `A` one by one to the function `X` and save the new matrix?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. The function `X` is perfectly well-defined for matrix argument `A`, as long as you do a left-division or element-wise division. Doing the whole thing element-wise (i.e., also the square) will give different results. Please clarify what it is you want to do.

Comment: I will make this more clear, I have a matric A=[58,58], and I need to calculate X and save it as a new matrix with dimensions [58,58]. X=(1+A^2 +cos theta)/(1+A), so in order to calculate  X and save it in the form of matrix, I need to process A matrix elements in X one by one. I hope its now clear. I know its a little confusing

Comment: What I mean is, `A^2 = A*A` (matrix-matrix multiply) is a valid operation and will yield a 58×58 matrix, and `A.^2 = A.*A` (repeated scalar-scalar multiply, element-wise) is a valid operation and will yield a 58×58 matrix. Which one do you need?

Answer (score 4):

You can calculate the power and inverse of each element using *element-wise* notation.

```
X = 1 + A.^2 + cos(theta) ./ (1+A);
```

Comment: I will make this more clear, I have a matric A=[58,58], and I need to calculate X and save it as a new matrix with dimensions [58,58]. X=(1+A^2 +cos theta)/(1+A), so in order to calculate the matrix X, I need to process A matrix elements in X one by one. I hope its now clear. I know its a little confusing.

Comment: @MaiAl-maghalsah what's wrong with the above answer ?
Did you try it yet. Notice the `.^` and `./` notation. They will do element wise operation on matrix `A` and the result will be saved in `X`